# Change tile colour on mouse hover in HTML,CSS

Tags: css, html

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 


.box {
  float: left;
  width: 175px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0.2em;
  background color: DarkGray;
}

.head{
color: green;
}

h1{
color: white;
text-align: center;
height: 2%;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
}

p{
color: LightSalmon;
text-align: center;
height: 5%;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
}
a:link{
   text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
   text-decoration: none;
}
a:active{
   text-decoration: none;
}
a :hover{
   text-decoration: none;color:green;background-color: yellow;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="head">
MY BLOCKS
</h1>
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank"><div class="box"><h1>Block0</h1><p>It is a floating Block0</p></div></a>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code, I need to change colour of my 'div' on mouse hover...I have tried almost everything i found online including tips from here. Didn't work. Please help. What can I replace for line,

```
a :hover{
       text-decoration: none;color:green;background-color: yellow;
    }
```

I have tried

```
.box a :hover{
           text-decoration: none;color:green;background-color: yellow;
        }
```

and

```
 a :hover box{
           text-decoration: none;color:green;background-color: yellow;
        }
```

and

```
 a box:hover{
           text-decoration: none;color:green;background-color: yellow;
        }
```

etc...

Comment: You have to remove space between `a :hover`. So your final selector should be: `a:hover .box { ... }`.

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use the hover state of the `a` tag.

`a:hover .box {color:green; background-color: yellow;}`